# How can I make an button with a clickable link to a website in Google Sheets?

Tags: button, google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

I want to create a button in Google Spreadsheets, with a link to a website.
Button creation works, hyperlink creation works in a cell, but combining these to I fail to do this.

I can add a script to the image/button but I don't find the right script who can help me?

Comment: Share what you tried.

Comment: I need a script to add on the button, but i don't find the right one.

Comment: This is a programmers forum. It's not really a place to to try and find pre-made scripts. A good question on stack overflow includes source code so we can test what you tried and figure out what you did wrong. This doesn't sound like a programming question, so I vote to close. I hope you can find another forum that can help you with this question!

Comment: Geweldig. Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure your response is sarcastic, but it's an honest attempt to send you in the right direction.  A good place to take a look might be superuser: https://superuser.com/

Or: share what you tried. Include source and do your best describing why your attempt didn't work and what the symptoms of your failure was. Good luck!

Comment: Evert, Thankyou for your response!